Why are they smiling at the camera?
The scene opens at the Stratton Oakmont office, where Donnie is frantically
clicking the ‘Enter’ and ‘Delete’ keys on his keyboard. Suddenly, the calm is
shattered as FBI agents storm into the office and begin arresting employees.
The camera cuts to Donnie, who is now sitting alone in his office, looking worried.
Jordan’s voiceover begins as the camera pans across the lobby, capturing the
smiling expressions of the employees:

JORDAN: I gave up everyone. And in return, I got three years in some hellhole in
Nevada I’d never even heard of. Like my pops, Mad Max, had said, ‘The chickens
had come home to roost.’ Whatever the fuck that means.


Why are they smiling at the camera?

The script indicates that is a flashback of all the people, eager young brokers and former colleagues alike, that Jordan "gave up" in order to lessen the severity of his sentence.
Look how they're smiling at him, unaware of the fact that he's ultimately going to betray them in order to save his own worthless hide.

235B INT. STRATTON OAKMONT III - BULLPEN - DAY 235B
Jordan stands addressing his 700 Brokers. WE SEE the eager young FACES, hanging on his every word.

